# How to find value of an expression if some cases are given>

Tags: function-construction

I actually need to find the value of x which have 3 cases as follows:

`x=0, when x<=0`

`x=[x], when x>0 and is non-integral`

`x=x-1, when x=1,2,3,...`

I don't have any idea how to find it in Mathematica. I use calculator in stead. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to define a function that transforms your input `x` to the desired output you can define a piecewise defined function somewhat like:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{0, x <= 0}, {IntegerPart[x], 
x > 0 && x =!= IntegerPart[x]}, {x - 1, x \[Element] Integers}}]
```

should do the job.

Comment: Thanks. I got some idea from the answer given. I've tried the following which seems to correct:   f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x^2,x<0},{2x,x>0}}]

Answer (score 0):

What about  `Floor[x] Boole[x > 0]`

```
Plot[Floor[x] Boole[x > 0], {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]